# In Django, how do I query a MYSQL database for the logged in user? (i.e results for specific user without hardcoding the user id)

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I have this so far, apologies I am new to programming - trying to learn Django and Python.

View:

```
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'app/dashboard.html', {'my_custom_sql': my_custom_sql})
```

## below function does't output anything in the template

```
def my_custom_sql(self):
    return self.request.CustomUser.customuser_set.all()
```

## alternative to above using hardcoded raw SQL:

```
def my_custom_sql():
 current_user = 1
 with connection.cursor() as cursor:
     cursor.execute("SELECT first_name FROM customuser WHERE id = 
     %s",[current_user])
     row = cursor.fetchone()
```

## above works, but I can't find a way of passing the userid to the query without hardcoding it into the user variable.

Template:

```
<h3> Displaying User's First Name </h3>

{% if user.is_authenticated %}

    <p>The first name: {{my_custom_sql}}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Welcome! You are telling us what you are expecting, but your code makes no attempt to solve it. StackOverflow is not a free code writing service, so you need to attempt the task before you can have an issue with it requiring help. It may just be a simple case of use. More info at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, Ignacio. I have attempted above - part of it works, my query is how I pass the logged in user to the current user variable or whether there is another way I can do it using the ORM. I'm new to this but struggling to find any material on solving the problem I've attempted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

andtmc. Welcome to SO.

You do need to close `if` tag:

**template**

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>The first name: {{my_custom_sql.first_name}}</p>
{% endif %}
```

**views.py**

```
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'app/dashboard.html', {'my_custom_sql': my_custom_sql(request)})

def my_custom_sql(request):
    return CustomUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
```

Depending on your model, you can just:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>The first name: {{user.first_name}}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks Eliakin. Apologies, I did have the close tag but i forgot to include it. My query doesn't work, do you know if what I am trying to do is achievable?

Comment: You're welcome, @andymc. Please don't forget to accept this answer. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks again. Have I explained properly what I am trying to do with running db queries for the user who is logged in? I haven't been able to find any information to make my queries work.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm getting an error stating: type object 'CustomUser' has no attribute 'customuser_set'     <do you know what that means? I've tried changing the 'set' to a column which I know is in the CustomUser model but it gives the same error but replaces set with username for example.

Comment: I've edited the question with a better answer @andymc